# How do I pipe a newline separated list as arguments to another command?

Tags: command-line, bash, pipe

So I have a list of usernames such as:

```
user1
user2
user3
```

I want to apply `id` on each of them and get something like:

```
uid=100(user1) gid=5(g1) groups=5(g1),6(g6),7(g10)
.
.
```

How can I achieve this? Please note that the list is the output of another command say `mycommand`.

Comment: What input does `mycommand` expect? Or is`mycommand`  a script of yours and you are asking how to give it the list of usernames as the input? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: it's a script of mine that gives that list as output

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xargs):

```
mycommand | xargs -L1 id
```

Example:

```
$ (echo root; echo nobody) | xargs -L1 id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
```

You can also loop over the input in bash:

```
mycommand | while read line
do
    id "$line"
done
```

`xargs` converts input to arguments of a command. The `-L1` option tells `xargs` to use each line as a sole argument to an invocation of the command.

Comment: If I know it is newline separated, and there is some danger that the input stream might contain spaces, I use '-d\n', as is:  `mycommand | xargs '-d\n' -L1 id`  Pretty much always a good idea, along with proper "$quoting" of all shell variables.

Comment: @SethRobertson very true. I left off the `-d '\n'` and `IFS= read -r` since the input is said to be usernames, I felt it might be overkill.

Comment: Maybe more clear: `echo -n "root nobody" | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -L 1 id`

Answer (score 5):

With bash, you can capture the lines of output into an array:

```
mapfile -t lines < <(mycommand)
```

And then iterate over them

```
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
    id "$line"
done
```

This is not as concise as xargs, but if you need the lines for more than one thing, it's pretty useful.

Comment: what does ` < <` mean?

Comment: The first `<` is the usual redirection of `mapfile`'s stdin. `<(...)` is a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) -- process substitutions are very useful to avoid issues due to pipelines running in subshells.

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -czf reloads.stage.tgz $(find . | egrep "sh$|functions$|sql$|setup$")
```

First I tested the `find/egrep` to make sure I get the list I want, then I added it as a file list at the end of the `tar` command.

Hope this helps somewhat.

1. `find .` just finds ALL the files under the current directory, though you could specify a subdirectory or a completely different path if you wish.
2. `egrep` just allows for multiple `grep` search strings separated by a pipe (`|`).
3. The rest should make sense after that.